# How to refresh fullcalendar using native javascript

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, laravel-8, fullcalendar-5

I'm using fullcalendar library.

I'm not using query with this library but native javascript. I'm able to create and delete events. But when I do I have to refresh to get it to show. I would like for the calendar to automatically refresh after an event is created or deleted.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        let model = document.getElementById('my-modal');

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            timeZone: 'UTC',
            initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
            headerToolbar: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            selectable: true,
            events: {!! $data !!},
            select: function(event) {
                let _token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
                let data = {
                    'title': 'Event 1',
                    'start': event.startStr,
                    'end': event.endStr,
                };
                fetch("{{ route('booking.calendar.create') }}", {
                    method: 'post',
                    data: data,
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': _token,
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(data),
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => console.log(data));
            },
            eventChange: function(e) {
                let _token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
                let data = {
                    'title': 'Event 1',
                    'start':e.event.start,
                    'end': e.event.end,
                };
                fetch("http://hair_booking.test/booking/update/" + e.event.id, {
                    method: 'post',
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': _token,
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(data),
                })
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => {

                    })
                    .catch(function (error){
                        console.log(error);
                    })
            },
            eventClick: function(e) {
                e.preventDefault;
                var event = confirm('Do you want to delete this event');

                if(event) {
                    let _token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
                    let data = {
                        'title': 'Event 1',
                        'start':e.event.start,
                        'end': e.event.end,
                    };
                    fetch('http://hair_booking.test/booking/delete/' + e.event.id, {
                        method: 'DELETE',
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': _token,
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify(data),
                    })
                        .then(response => {
                            response.json()
                        })
                        .then(data => data)
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.error(error);
                        });
                }
            }
        });

        calendar.render();
    });
```

Here's my laravel route file

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function() {
    Route::get('/booking', [HairBooking::class, 'render'])->name('booking.calendar');
    Route::post('/booking/create', [HairBooking::class, 'create'])->name('booking.calendar.create');
    Route::post('/booking/update/{id}', [HairBooking::class, 'updateEvent'])->name('booking.calendar.update');
    Route::delete('/booking/delete/{id}', [HairBooking::class, 'deleteEvent'])->name('booking.calendar.delete');
});
```

Here's my Component blade file to populate the events.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Booking;
use Carbon\CarbonImmutable;
use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HairBooking extends Component
{
    public function create(Request $request) {

        $booking = new Booking();
        $booking->title= 'Event 1';
        $booking->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $booking->start = $request->input('start');
        $booking->end = $request->input('end');

        $booking->save();

        return $booking;
    }

    public function updateEvent(Request $request, $id) {
        $event = Booking::find($id);

        $event->start = $request->input('start');
        $event->end = $request->input('end');

        $event->save();

        return $event;
    }

    public function deleteEvent(Request $request, $id) {
        $event = Booking::find($id);

        $event->delete();

        return response()->json(null, 204);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $data = Booking::all()->toJson();
        return view('livewire.hair-booking', [
            'data' => $data
        ]);
    }
}
```

And here's my model really bare model.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Booking extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'title',
        'start',
        'end',
        'allDay'
    ];
    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $casts = [
      'start' => 'datetime',
      'end' => 'datetime'
    ];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can either a) add the event directly to fullCalendar when your fetch() function completes (using https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEvent), or turn your `events` feed into a dynamic feed which can fetch data from the server on-demand (rather than being just a static array of data), and then you can call https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-refetchEvents after your fetch() call has completed, to make it reload from the server. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed for info about defining an event feed URL.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you give an example. I've been looking at the docs and I'm stuch on refetchEvents.

Comment: stuck how exactly? It's just a function you call, and there's an example given in the docs. What specifically is the problem you're having?

Comment: In the code provided where would you place the refetchEvents function? I've added it to the end of fetch call and it's not working for me. Maybe I'm calling the function wrong.

Comment: Have you also converted your events into a feed rather than a static list? Refetch will have no effect unless you do that (because it has nowhere to fetch anything from if you don't specify a URL or a callback to get them from). Please update the question to show precisely what changes you've made.

Comment: Ok I added more code to show what I'm doing maybe I'm approaching it wrong.

Comment: Well none of what you've shown seems to try and implement any of the things in those links. There's no event feed, no refetch, and alternatively no calls to addEvent instead. So where exactly are you getting stuck, it's hard to give advice on what's wrong without seeing any kind of attempt to follow the documentation

Comment: I'm not using addEvent I'm using select function to create the event's. I using api endpoints to add, update, or delete events. Like I specified most of it works just not refreshing when I select a time frame or delete. But if I manually refresh the browser my changes show. I just want to automatically update without me having to manually refresh.

Comment: select doesn't actually create an event in fullCalendar though, it just allows you to respond to the selection of a time. If you want the event to show on fullCalendar after you've sent it to the API then you need to call addEvent, as I mentioned in my very first comment. Or you need to follow the alternative approach I mentioned, involving creating an event feed and using refetchEvents. Those are your options, now you need to choose an approach and implement it, using the documentation to help. You can ask here again if you get stuck and can show some code which isn't working as you wanted

Comment: Thanks @ADyson I was able to get it working. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.